# Android Firestore makes app restart

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm using Firebase Firestore to store data without sever. However, I think I had a problem with a snapshot listener from Firestore. Below is the code i used.

**Snapshot Listener that is making a problem**

```
register = FireStore.getUserInfo(firestore, uid).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        Log.d("Snapshot Listener", "Calling");
        String source = documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites() ? "local" : "server";
        if(documentSnapshot != null & documentSnapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d("Snapshot Listener", source + " data :" + documentSnapshot.getData());
        } else {
            Log.d("Snapshot Listener", source + " data : null");
        }
        currentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("Snapshot Listener", "Point is updated.");
                tvBoneNum.setText(String.valueOf(currentUser.getPoint()));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**User.class - Sorry for Korean words**

```
@Data
public class User {
    private String uid; // 유저의 고유 아이디
    private String token; // 유저의 파이어베이스 토큰
    private String email; // 유저의 이메일 값.
    private String photo1; // 유저의 첫번째 사진 NonNull
    private String photo2; // 유저의 두번째 사진 NonNull
    private String photo3; // 유저의 세번째 사진 Nullable
    private String audio; // 유저의 음성 녹음 기록
    private int point; // 유저의 현재 포인트 갯수
    private String nicname; // 유저의 닉네임
    private String gender; // 유저의 성별
    private String birth; // 유저의 생년월일
    private String location; // 유저의 거주지 주소
    private Double lat; // 거주지 주소의 위도
    private Double lon; // 거주지 주소의 경도
    private String ableTime; // 유저의 산책 가능 시간
    private String personality; // 유저의 성격
    private String job; // 유저의 직업
    private Boolean isPet; // 반려인 여부 true면 반려인 false면 비반려인
    private String objective; // 유저의 가입 목적
    private String introduce; // 유저의 소개글
    private String dogName; // 유저의 강아지 이름
    private String dogGender; // 유저의 강아지 성별
    private String dogBirth; // 유저의 강아지 탄생일
    private String dogKind; // 유저의 강아지 종류
    private String dogSize; // 유저의 강아지 크기
    private String dogPersonality; // 유저의 강아지 성격
    @Getter @Setter private String isSter; // 유저의 강아지 중성화여부
    private String social; // 유저의 강아지 사회성
    private String poop; // 유저의 강아지 배변훈련
    private String obey; // 유저의 강아지 복종정도
    private String sports; // 유저의 강아지 스포츠 훈련 정도
    private int amount; // 유저의 평점 총점
    private int count; // 유저의 평점 갯수
    private int average; // 유저의 평점 평균
    private int fiveReceived; // 별 5개 받은 횟수
    private int fourReceived; // 별 4개 받은 횟수
    private int threeReceived; // 별 3개 받은 횟수
    private int twoReceived; // 별 2개 받은 횟수
    private int oneReceived; // 별 1개 받은 횟수
    private int afterFiveReceived; // 매너 별 5개 받은 횟수
    private int afterFourReceived; // 매너 별 4개 받은 횟수
    private int afterThreeReceived; // 매너 별 3개 받은 횟수
    private int afterTwoReceived; // 매너 별 2개 받은 횟수
    private int afterOneReceived; // 매너 별 1개 받은 횟수
    private int afterAmount; // 매너 후기 총점
    private int afterCount; // 매너 갯수
    private int afterAverage; // 매너 평균
    private int audioAmount; // 음성 총점
    private int audioCount; // 음성 평가 갯수
    private int audioAverage; // 음성 평점 평균
    private boolean isRest; // 휴면 계정 여부
    private String joinDate; // 가입 날짜
    private Boolean isNoti;
    private Boolean didApplyFilter; // 필터를 적용했는지 여부를 표시
    private String snsAccount; // 사용자 SNS 계정 종류
    private String isMarried; // 기혼 여부
    private String trainDegree; // 비반려인이 원하는 훈련 정도
    private int birthYear; // 유저의 출생년도
    private int remainCard; // 남은 카드 개수
    private boolean mannerUnlock; // 매너 잠금 해제 여부
    private boolean reviewUnlock; // 리뷰 잠금 해제 여부
    private Date mannerUnlockDate; // 매너 잠금 해제 한 날
    private Date reviewUnlockDate; // 리뷰 잠금 해제 한 날
}
```

When the values of User class changes, and update these values into firestore, snapshot listener is supposed to acknowledge onEvent() method and process below code of onEvent method, but it makes my app restart. Other snapshot listeners don't make app restart. I can't figure out reason of this problem. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the logic of getting the data from the database inside the if statement. Your data might be `null`. So in case of nullity, those lines of code do not need to be executed. That's why you get your app restared.

```
register = FireStore.getUserInfo(firestore, uid).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        Log.d("Snapshot Listener", "Calling");
        String source = documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites() ? "local" : "server";
        if(documentSnapshot != null & documentSnapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d("Snapshot Listener", source + " data :" + documentSnapshot.getData());

            currentUser = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Snapshot Listener", "Point is updated.");
                    tvBoneNum.setText(String.valueOf(currentUser.getPoint()));
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d("Snapshot Listener", source + " data : null");
        }
    }
});
```